# GDB disas question about address values

Tags: gdb, stack, return-value, disassembly

I'm working with a binary file that I disas'd in gdb. Right now I'm just examining the return value of a function.

```
0x08048604 <playGame+78>: ret
```

Is the address shown the address where ret is stored in the function? Or is it just the address of the instruction to return the ret value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the adress from `.text` section where the `ret` instruction is stored. You can add some local variables to your functions and print their addresses, which will be very different, since locals are stored on stack, and stack is usually far away from the actual executable code.